# What does "transmit buffer" and "receive buffer" mean in the UART context?

Tags: c, uart

My understanding of what a transmit/receive buffer is largely related to ethernet systems, where some data is stored in the buffer before the whole data is transmitted. Is this the same with UART, where some data is stored in a UART transmit/receive buffer until there are 8 bits (thus filling up the UART capacity) or when the system is ordered to send the data from the buffer?

The reason I am asking this is because I am looking at some C code for the [MSP430FR5994 MCU](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau367p/slau367p.pdf?ts=1649150529600&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMSP430FR5969) involving UART and I'd like to fully understand the code. Please let me know if more info is needed to answer my question.

The code in question, if anyone's interested. The code runs fine, I just want to know what the buffer does in UART.

```
#include <msp430.h>

char RXbuffer[32];
const unsigned char maxRXbytes = sizeof(RXbuffer);
unsigned char RXbytes = 0;

const char message[] = "ok\n";
const unsigned char messageLength = sizeof(message);
unsigned char TXbytes = 0;

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;               // Stop Watchdog


    // Configure GPIO
    P2SEL0 &= ~(BIT0 | BIT1);
    P2SEL1 |= (BIT0 | BIT1);                // USCI_A0 UART operation (p93_s)

    // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
    // previously configured port settings
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;

    // Startup clock system with max DCO setting ~8MHz
    CSCTL0_H = CSKEY_H;                       // Unlock CS registers
    CSCTL1 = DCOFSEL_3 | DCORSEL;             // Set DCO to 8MHz
    CSCTL2 = SELA__VLOCLK | SELS__DCOCLK | SELM__DCOCLK;
    CSCTL3 = DIVA__1 | DIVS__1 | DIVM__1;     // Set all dividers
    CSCTL0_H = 0;                             // Lock CS registers

    // Configure USCI_A0 for UART mode
    UCA0CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                    // Put eUSCI in reset (p788)
    UCA0CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK;             // CLK = SMCLK
    // Baud Rate calculation for 19200
    // 8000000/(16*19200) = 26.042
    // Fractional portion = 0.042
    // User's Guide Table 21-4: UCBRSx = 0xD6
    // UCBRFx = int ( (52.083-52)*16) = 1
    UCA0BRW = 26;                           // 8000000/16/19200, p789
    UCA0MCTLW |= UCOS16 | UCBRF_1 | 0xD600; // UCOS16 = Oversampling enable, used when high frequency clk is used, probably divides everything by 16, UCBRF = fine turner when UCOS16 is active
                                            // 0xD600 is for first 8 bits,
    UCA0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                  // Initialize eUSCI
    UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;                       // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt

    __bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits | GIE);       // Enter LPM3, interrupts enabled
    __no_operation();                         // For debugger
}

#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=EUSCI_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_A0_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(EUSCI_A0_VECTOR))) USCI_A0_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
    switch(__even_in_range(UCA0IV,USCI_UART_UCTXCPTIFG))
    {
      case USCI_NONE: break;
      case USCI_UART_UCRXIFG:

          if(RXbytes < maxRXbytes)
          {
              // Get the byte
              RXbuffer[RXbytes] = UCA0RXBUF;

              // Check for either ASCII carriage return '\r', or linefeed '\n' character.
              // If true enable the TX interrupt to send response message
              if((RXbuffer[RXbytes] == '\r') || (RXbuffer[RXbytes] ==  '\n'))
              {
                  // Start message transmission
                  UCA0IE |= UCTXIE;

                  // Reset receive buffer index
                  RXbytes = 0;
              }
              else
                  RXbytes++;

          }
          break;

      case USCI_UART_UCTXIFG:

          // Transmit the byte
          UCA0TXBUF = message[TXbytes++];

          // If last byte sent, disable the interrupt
          if(TXbytes == messageLength)
          {
              UCA0IE &= ~UCTXIE;
              TXbytes = 0;
          }
          break;

      case USCI_UART_UCSTTIFG: break;
      case USCI_UART_UCTXCPTIFG: break;
      default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `The transmit data buffer is user accessible and holds the data waiting to be
moved into the transmit shift register and transmitted on UCAxTXD. Writing to
the transmit data buffer clears UCTXIFG. The MSB of UCAxTXBUF is not used and is reset` page 791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are software buffers and hardware buffers.

The UART hardware peripheral has hardware buffers, a rx buffer where received data is waiting to get handled by the program, and a tx buffer where data is waiting for the MCU to transmit it (a tx complete flag will get set). In some MCUs these are just 1 byte large each. Others have a larger rx buffers following a FIFO principle.

`UCA0TXBUF` in your example appears to be this tx buffer/data register and apparently it is just 1 byte large. `USCI_UART_UCTXIFG` appears to be the flag set upon transmission complete and it's set to generate an interrupt when done.

The `RXbuffer` in your example is a software buffer used by the UART driver.

---

Unrelated to your question, this code has several problems and latent bugs waiting to explode:

- Using `char` for raw data is always incorrect, since `char` has implementation-defined signedness and might turn into negative number if you store raw data in the MSB. It is not a portable type and shouldn't be used for anything but text strings. Use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` instead.
- There is no protection from race conditions in your code, so in case the main program is accessing `RXbuffer` while the ISR is writing to it, you will get all manner of weird bugs.
- There is no protection against incorrect compiler optimizations. In case your compiler doesn't realize that an ISR is never called by software but by hardware, the optimizer might break the code. To prevent this all shared variables should be declared `volatile` (same goes in case you would use DMA buffers instead).

  Check out:

  - [Avoiding global variables when using interrupts in embedded systems](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329339/avoiding-global-variables-when-using-interrupts-in-embedded-systems/329961#329961)
  - [Using volatile in embedded C development](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102)
- Microcontroller systems do not return from main() so `int main (void)` is always wrong. You should use the implementation-defined form `void main (void)` (use `-ffreestanding` if compiling with gcc) and end the `main()` function with a `for(;;) {}` loop.
- You probably want to handle UART framing errors = data corruption or wrong baudrate, as well as UART overrun errors = hardware buffers were overwritten before MCU emptied them. These are typically available through interrupt flags too.

Comment: `void main(void)` doesn't mean it will never return, and `int main(void)` doesn't mean it will return. You might have to use `void main(void)`, but not for the reason you gave.

Comment: @ikegami You have to use `void main (void)` because otherwise the code calling main() might crap up the stack with garbage that never gets freed and you've created a memory leak of sorts. Depending on setup, main() is either called from a reset vector or a CRT. And depending on how that's written as well as calling convention, a function with a return type may or may not require the stack.

Comment: Anyway, the `for(;;){}` loop is the important part. Suffering a stack memory leak of some 1 to 4 bytes might not be a big deal in some systems.

Comment: There's no memory leak. Even if a stack is used (which could very well not be the case for an `int`-sized return value), it would only be used on exit, and you said the function never exits. You have to use the convention required by the system, period. (I have no idea what the required convention for the system in question. I'm not arguing that `void main(void)` is wrong, just that both of the reasons you gave are wrong.)

Comment: @ikegami Oh so function return addresses aren't stacked before a function is called? I have no idea what computer _you_ are talking about, I'm talking about 100% of the existing stack-based computers in the real world... The idea is to not call main() through a normal subroutine call which involves stacking.

Comment: The return address is stacked no matter what (assuming a stack if used instead of a fixed location). It is stacked for `int main(void)`, but it is also stacked for `void main(void)` too. Again, `void main(void)` doesn't indicate that a function doesn't return; it simply indicate that if/when it does, it doesn't return a value.

Comment: (Or maybe the return address is never stacked for `main` on that machine. That would be more complicated. But whatever. Still has nothing to do with the prototype.)